# Whats this bug?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image][image]

My friend found this bug today and we are trying to find out what it is. Long black (about an inch and a half).

Comment: Please edit the question and add the location (city/state/country) where you took this image.

Answer (score 7):

Meloid beetle (blister beetle).  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berberomeloe) images suggest genus *Berberomeloe*.  This one below, from Spain, is identified on the Wiki page as *Berberomeloe majalis*. There is at least one other species described from the genus (*insignis*).

[image]